# Авторизация при помощи VK SDK

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

Как можно получить доступ vk аккаунта? 
В facebook есть FBSDKLogginButton(), а в вк нету. 
Я пробовал вешать

```
 @IBAction func vkAutorize(_ sender: UIButton) {
    VKSdk.authorize(["photos"])
}
```

но выдает ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно войти в аккаунт VK??

Так же при VKSdk.authorize(scope) выдает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас делегаты реализованы? авторизация/инициализация в ВК? Вы документацию читали?)

Comment: Да читал но все равно как-то все туго. (не давно начал просто). Делегаты были реализованы.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно авторизовать пользователя, потом использовать его фото и т.д.:

```
    let SCOPE = ["wall", "photos", "email", "friends"] //то к чему нужно получить доступ см. VKPermissions.h

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         //Initialize SDK with your APP_ID for any delegate.
                    VKSdk.initialize(withAppId: VK_ID).register(self)
    ...
    }

   func vkButtonPressed(){
        self.initWorkingBlock { (finished) -> Void in
        // пользователь авторизован
        }
    }

func initWorkingBlock (_ completion: ((Bool) -> Void)!){

        VKSdk.wakeUpSession(SCOPE as [AnyObject], complete: { (state, error) -> Void in
            if (state == VKAuthorizationState.authorized) {
                print("Authorized and ready to go")
            } else if ((error) != nil) {
                print("Some error happend, but you may try later: \(error)")
            } else {
                VKSdk.authorize(self.SCOPE as [AnyObject])
            }
            completion(true)
            self.vkGetUser()
            print("completion VKSdk.wakeUpSession")
        })
    }
func vkGetUser(){
        if VKSdk.isLoggedIn() {
            let userId = VKSdk.accessToken().userId
            if (userId != nil) {
                VKApi.users().get([VK_API_FIELDS:"first_name, last_name, id, photo_100, sex, bdate, country",
                    VK_API_USER_ID: userId]).execute(resultBlock: { (response) -> Void in

                         let user = response?.parsedModel.fields[0] as! VKUser

                        print("Пользователь ВК: \(user.fields)")

                        }, errorBlock: { (error) -> Void in
                            print("Error2: \(error)")
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

И ниже делегаты

Comment: также в Info.plist добавить  url схему если авторизация через приложение VKapp, и настройки NSAppTransportSecurity